# filter for rows with n largest values for each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

#### Context

I want, for each team, the rows of the data frame that contains the top three scoring players.

In my head, it is a combination of `Dataframe.nlargest()` and `Dataframe.groupby()` but I don't think this is supported.
My ideal solution is:

- performed directly on `df` without having to create other dataframes
- legible, and
- relatively performant (real df shape is 7M rows and 5 col)

#### Input

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('{"team":{"0":"A","1":"A","2":"A","3":"A","4":"A","5":"B","6":"B","7":"B","8":"B","9":"B","10":"C","11":"C","12":"C","13":"C","14":"C"},"player":{"0":"Alice","1":"Becky","2":"Carmen","3":"Donna","4":"Elizabeth","5":"Fran","6":"Greta","7":"Heather","8":"Iris","9":"Jackie","10":"Kelly","11":"Lucy","12":"Molly","13":"Nina","14":"Ophelia"},"points":{"0":15,"1":11,"2":13,"3":8,"4":10,"5":28,"6":29,"7":18,"8":25,"9":9,"10":12,"11":23,"12":18,"13":10,"14":15}}')
```

```
| team | player    | points |
|------|-----------|--------|
| A    | Alice     | 15     |
| A    | Becky     | 11     |
| A    | Carmen    | 13     |
| A    | Donna     | 8      |
| A    | Elizabeth | 10     |
| B    | Fran      | 28     |
| B    | Greta     | 29     |
| B    | Heather   | 18     |
| B    | Iris      | 25     |
| B    | Jackie    | 9      |
| C    | Kelly     | 12     |
| C    | Lucy      | 23     |
| C    | Molly     | 18     |
| C    | Nina      | 10     |
| C    | Ophelia   | 15     |
```

#### Desired Output

```py
df_output = pd.read_json('{"team":{"0":"A","1":"A","2":"A","3":"B","4":"B","5":"B","6":"C","7":"C","8":"C"},"player":{"0":"Alice","1":"Becky","2":"Carmen","3":"Fran","4":"Greta","5":"Iris","6":"Lucy","7":"Molly","8":"Ophelia"},"points":{"0":15,"1":11,"2":13,"3":28,"4":29,"5":25,"6":23,"7":18,"8":15}}')
df_output
```

```
| team | player  | points |
|------|---------|--------|
| A    | Alice   | 15     |
| A    | Becky   | 11     |
| A    | Carmen  | 13     |
| B    | Fran    | 28     |
| B    | Greta   | 29     |
| B    | Iris    | 25     |
| C    | Lucy    | 23     |
| C    | Molly   | 18     |
| C    | Ophelia | 15     |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[`df.groupby.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.rank.html)** method:

```
In [1401]: df[df.groupby('team')['points'].rank(ascending=False) <= 3]
Out[1401]: 
   team   player  points
0     A    Alice      15
1     A    Becky      11
2     A   Carmen      13
5     B     Fran      28
6     B    Greta      29
8     B     Iris      25
11    C     Lucy      23
12    C    Molly      18
14    C  Ophelia      15
```

Comment: picking this answer b/c its 7X faster than @Ch3steR's approach

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`df.nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html)

```
df.groupby('team').apply(lambda x:x.nlargest(3,'points')).reset_index(drop=True)

  team   player  points
0    A    Alice      15
1    A   Carmen      13
2    A    Becky      11
3    B    Greta      29
4    B     Fran      28
5    B     Iris      25
6    C     Lucy      23
7    C    Molly      18
8    C  Ophelia      15
```

Comment: ok yeah this is what i was looking for. to clarify. the `x` var in groupby-apply lambda is would be the subset of rows that belong to a particular group? and `type(x)==Dataframe`? For some reason I thought `x` would be a row...

Comment: @AndersSwanson Yes, `x` is `DataFrame`. `for k,g in df.groupby('team'): print(k)` should give you idea about each group's DataFrame.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might work -

```
df.loc[df.groupby(['team'])['points'].nlargest(3).reset_index().drop(['team','points'], axis=1)['level_1'].values]
   team   player  points
0     A    Alice      15
2     A   Carmen      13
1     A    Becky      11
6     B    Greta      29
5     B     Fran      28
8     B     Iris      25
11    C     Lucy      23
12    C    Molly      18
14    C  Ophelia      15
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is `sort_values` and `groupby().tail/head`:

```
df.sort_values('points').groupby('team').tail(3)
```

Output:

```
   team   player  points
1     A    Becky      11
2     A   Carmen      13
0     A    Alice      15
14    C  Ophelia      15
12    C    Molly      18
11    C     Lucy      23
8     B     Iris      25
5     B     Fran      28
6     B    Greta      29
```

Or

```
df.sort_values('points', ascending=False).groupby('team').head(3)
```

Output:

```
   team   player  points
6     B    Greta      29
5     B     Fran      28
8     B     Iris      25
11    C     Lucy      23
12    C    Molly      18
0     A    Alice      15
14    C  Ophelia      15
2     A   Carmen      13
1     A    Becky      11
```